# Nservice bus: Different sagas started with the same event

Tags: nservicebus

Is it that possible to start different sagas with the same started message and the same endpoint?

For example i want to handle a message "user-signed-in".

And i have a 2 different sagas which should start with the above message:

1. Will wait until user signed out and will publish some event.
2. The second will wait until he purchase some product and will publish event.

That sagas are completly diffrenet and have different class name & saga data class name.

And question is: will both sagas start when "user-signed-in" message come?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single message received by an endpoint **can** start multiple sagas.

You will need to mark both sagas as started by that message type. For example:

```
public class UserSessionSaga : IAmStartedByMessages<UserSignedIn>...
```

and

```
public class UserPurchasesSaga : IAmStartedByMessages<UserSignedIn>...
```

`UserSessionSaga` will be completed by an event (signing out) that is different from an event completing `UserPurchasesSaga`. For that, you'll have to specify what additional messages each saga can handle using `IHandleMessages<T>` and  correlate all the messages each saga can handle. See [documentation here](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/message-correlation) for the syntax.

Comment: For example i want to handle a message "user-signed-in".

And i have a 2 different sagas which should start with the above message:

Will wait until user signed out and will publish some event.
The second will wait until he purchase some product and will publish event.
That sagas are completly diffrenet and have different class name & saga data class name.

And question is: will both sagas start when "user-signed-in" message come?

Comment: so it will be different sagas in different tables.

Comment: Thanks @digger. The update completely changes the answer. Yes, you can do what you are planning to. Documentation has an [example](https://docs.particular.net/samples/saga/simple/) with a single saga that could be used to build up the scenario you're talking about to get you going.